# Can autobench do basic authentication?

Tags: perl, basic-authentication, load-testing, autobench

How can I run the [autobench](http://www.xenoclast.org/autobench/) tool using basic authentication?

I can run [httperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/) with basic auth but I have not been able to run autobench using it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add `httperf` options into the `autobench` configuration file. Extra options are simply passed through; look up the call stack lines 149, 299, 236, 78.

I did not run the software to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

Add

`httperf_add-header = 'Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXX=\n'`

To your

`.autobench.conf`

To pass arguemnts to `httperf` prepend `httperf_` to any option in your `.autobench.conf`